# Is it safe to Upgrade mysql 5.1 to 5.5 on my vps?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a virtual server with CPANEL-whm and I see a possibility to Upgrade the mysql to 5.5, 
Is it safe ?

Comment: If you don't need any of the new functionality and there are no security reasons I see no reason to update. Regarding the question about safety - no one can tell you for sure.

Comment: There are many dependencies that you may need to resolve. 
Depending on your Liunux distro and package manager, some of these dependencies could enforce specific versions and some will allow the upgrades to occur.

Without knowing what precisely you system entails, there's no single answer to this.

Comment: if i'm upgrade to 5.5, Do I need to change something in my website (PHP) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [upgrade PHP 5 on Plesk 9.2.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568613/upgrade-php-5-on-plesk-9-2-1)

Answer (score 2):

No one could guarantee you that.

And if someone says it is safe - don't trust them

PS: the rule of thumb: it works - don't touch it

Upgrades without some particular reason (ie some bug your software affected by was fixed) never lead to something good

Answer (score 0):

It depends : do you use some functionnalities that are not available and/or were updated between the two versions? etc.

Best way to know : try on another server, test the application, if everything works then do it on your live production server.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the migration guide:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html

There is not many huge differences, mostly just how the InnoDB plugin works internally, and some encoding stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Test it. Install mysql 5.1 on your own machine or some machine that isn't critical then upgrade to mysql 5.5. Then run any tests that you might have. On VPS you usually have free reign about what's installed and what isn't so you should be able to install anything you catch in your testing.

If you don't have any tests, familiarize yourself with the changes made in the upgrade and determine if there will be any immediate impact from the changes.

Never just upgrade because.